Make g++ prefer standard header files
I'm working with an old embedded system, and I would like to get the files compiling on my Linux desktop with a modern C++ compiler (e.g. g++12) for some testing.  I've done this before with similar codes, and it turned out to be pretty handy.
In the case the problem is that the embedded system used gcc 2.7, which predates C++ standardization in 1998.  As part of this, they have gcc's 2.7's header files mixed in with the embedded system header files. (e.g. iostream and iostream.h)
Of course, these old headers can't be built by a modern compiler. So, I'd like them to be ignored.  So, for example, if #include <iostream> I would like to get g++12's version, not the version from the embedded system (gcc2.7)  But when I use -I, g++ will search the -I files first.
For example: g++ -c -I<embedded header dir> file.c  will search embedded header dir first, and therefore find that version of iostream.  Which doesn't work.
How can I get g++12 to prefer it's own iostream to the <embedded header dir> one?

To clarify: The embedded code has includes like #include <iostream.h> in the code and you want the PC to sub that out with #include <iostream> when building?

Pity the .h makes it impossible to be really dumb and  have a header full of poison like #define iostream.h iostream

Huh. Preprocessor's not dumb enough to let you do that anyway: https://godbolt.org/z/35erezn75 . Learned something today!

What if you added a folder of symlinks mapping each of the old headers to the Standard headers and added `-I to the commandline?

I second the extra folder, but maintaining symlinks will just drive you crazy. Have the folder contain stubs, so that iostream.h will just contain the one line #include <iostream>.

@user4581301 No, that was a little confusing.  The embedded system standard library DOES have both iostream and iostream.h (Where one just #includes the other) but I don't care about that.
The problem is WHICH iostream gets included.  I want the one from gcc12, not from the weird old embedded system.
My currently solution is just to change all the embedded system header files to make them compatible with the modern compiler, but I was hoping for a better way.

Have you tried g++ -idirafter <embedded header dir> ? See gcc documentation: Options for Directory Search.
